# Iterating through a CSV file column to check whether a string is present using python

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement

I have a csv file with a Target column. I use pandas to read the csv. I want the user to add a string and iterate through the csv file's Target column, if the string is present, then I print, if it's not, I ask the user to re-enter the string. However, whatever I do it, doesn't recognise the input string, despite it being in the file, and I constantly get the prompt to enter again.

```
rawdata = pd.read_csv("pcr.csv")
targetlist = rawdata["Target"]
gene1 = input("Enter a gene: ")
for item in targetlist:   #I have also used in rawdata["Target"] without success
    if gene1 == item:
        print("Gene 1: " + gene1)
    else:
        gene1 = input("Not found. Enter again: ")
```

Comment: Please include some sample lines from the csv, and sample input that you would consider a match.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Use the Pandas dataframe instead of a loop

```
df = pd.read_csv("pcr.csv")
gene1 = input("Enter a gene: ")
df["match_gene1"] = df.Target == gene1
```

Then you can get the Series of matching Targets:

`matching_targets = df[df.match_gene1].Targets`

This works because `df.match_gene1` is a Boolean series, acting as a row selection condition.

2. Do you really want an *exact* match?

The statement `df.Target == gene1` requires a case-sensitive exact match.  If that's not what you are looking for, please update your question with inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your else is IN your for statement.
the problem with this is..
it reads the first item,
if the first item doesn't match, it asks you to enter again.
thus, it doesn't iterate through every item.
I would fix this by doing something more like this :

```python
rawdata = pd.read_csv("pcr.csv")
targetlist = rawdata["Target"]

while True:  
  gene1 = input("Enter a gene: ")
  check = False # Make this boolean
  for item in targetlist:   
    if gene1 == item:
        print("Gene 1: " + gene1)
        ckeck = True
        
  if check == True:
    break
  else:
    print("could not find gene, please enter again")
```